# How to find radius of a sphere by its given bounds and center in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, geometry

Let's say I've had a Circle drawn on my Google map and I've stored its bounds (north east corner and south west corner) given by Circle.getBounds() and its center. But I didn't store radius of the circle.

Now I want to restore (draw once again on the map) my circle, but I only have its bounds and center, while Circle constructor requires its radius ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#CircleOptions)).

Is there a way to recalculate the radius?

P.S. The distance between one of the bounds points and the circle's  center doesn't fit here as the circle lies inside its bound rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get distance between points `[Lat_north_east, Lng_Center]` (top middle) and `[Lat_Center, Lng_Center]`. This is meridional arc, so distance formula is simple:

```
R = 40 000 000 * Abs(Lat_north_east - Lat_Center) / 360
```

40 000 km is full length of earth meridian - full circle, 360 degrees.

So `40 000 000  meters / 360 = 111.111 km` is length of one-degree meridional arc.

Comment: Thank you sir! You may want to explain more about the formula, to comply better with Stackoverflow "good answer" policy, but I'm accepting your answer anyway.